# StaleElementReferenceException | WebDriver losing reference after function call

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape products listed on https://www.ethicon.com/. My approach is to start with

1. scraping product links from [product list page](https://www.jnjmedicaldevices.com/en-US/company/ethicon/products)
2. find all variant link pages from category pages (From Product Specifications in [sample](https://www.jnjmedicaldevices.com/en-US/product/echelon-contour-curved-cutter-stapler))
3. extract relevant details from the variant page

I am testing with moving from 2 -> 3 as of now. I am trying with
this code ([full code](http://pythonfiddle.com/stale-element-error))

```
  def fetch_productlinks(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    # print(elems[0].get_attribute("href"))
    counter = 0
    for elem in elems:
      elem_url = elem.get_attribute("href")
      if re.match(".*/code/.*", elem_url):
        # print(elem_url)
        if counter <= 1: 
          self.extract_imagesandmetadata(elem_url, self.driver)          
          counter += 1

  def extract_imagesandmetadata(self, url, driver):
    # driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
    before_window = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
    driver.get(url)
    after_window = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(after_window)
    print("Crawling ..." + url)
    html = driver.page_source
    if html:
      self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
      pimg = self.soup.find('img', {'class': 'img-responsive'})
      
      if pimg:
        print(pimg["src"])
        self.tempdict["pimg"] = self.img_base_path + pimg["src"]
      else:
        self.tempdict["pimg"] = ""

      ptitle = self.soup.find('h1', {'class': 'eprc-title'})

      if ptitle:
        print(self.sanitize_text(ptitle.text))
        self.tempdict["ptitle"] = self.sanitize_text(ptitle.text)
      else:
        self.tempdict["ptitle"] = ""

      self.tempdict["purl"] = url
    self.outdict.append(self.tempdict)
    driver.switch_to.window(before_window)
```

and getting below error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: 
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

which I believe I am getting because the webdriver is losing the reference after the function call. I am calling fetch_productlinks from the main function.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I have not downvoted, but this question is more prone to getting more downvotes, you have given a link to your code, Instead you should update your question with the code (minimal code which is causing the issue not entire code).

Answer (score 0):

The basics of selenium are that you locate an `element` by one of selenium's locators. One assumes once you have the element you can interact with it, and life is easy. Typically it's not, because any interaction with the page, can cause the DOM to re-render making your element something that no longer exists. That is simplified explanation, it can get way worse, but we will stick with this simple concept for now.

You need to accept that the DOM has the potential to re-render at the most inopportune times. Once you accept this, you start to think in terms of `how to recover` and what is the acceptable limits of `recovery`.

Below I have some pseudo code to give you an idea of how to recover.
In the pseudo code I have two classes which semi-mimic your troubled code section.

The first class is called `PseudoClass1`:
What `PseudoClass1` does is just simply save your data to memory and if we manage to receive no errors, move that data to its desired location. This assumes memory usage is not a problem.

The second class is called `PseudoClass2`:
What `PseudoClass2` does is just simply save your data to a temporary directory and if we manage to receive no errors, move that data to its desired location. This assumes memory usage is a problem, so we write to a temp location then move it to the final destination.

```py
import os
import re
import tempfile

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

# We are assuming the webdriver is right next to this file
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'chromedriver')


class PseudoClass1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
        self.cache = {}

    def save_images_plus_meta_into_memory(self, url):
        """Does some work and saves whatever you want into self.cache"""

    def move_images_plus_meta_into_desired_location(self):
        """Take whatever has been safely processed in self.cache and move it to the desired location"""

    def fetch_productlinks_saved_in_memory(self, url):
        """If you have no memory constraints save the values into memory"""
        self.driver.get(url)
        retries = 1
        max_retries = 10
        while retries <= max_retries:
            self.cache = {}
            retries += 1
            try:
                elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
                counter = 0
                for elem in elems:
                    elem_url = elem.get_attribute("href")
                    if re.match(".*/code/.*", elem_url):
                        if counter <= 1:
                            self.save_images_plus_meta_into_memory(elem_url)
                            counter += 1
                # If are here, you did not get a stale element reference
                # You can now transfer data to the desired place
                self.move_images_plus_meta_into_desired_location()
                return  # Exit out of the retry loop
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                print(f'Retry count: {retries}')
                continue
        raise Exception('Failed to fetch product links')


class PseudoClass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)

    def save_images_plus_meta_into_a_temp_dir(self, url, temp_dir):
        """Does some work and saves whatever you want into the temp_dir location"""

    def move_images_plus_meta_into_desired_location(self, temp_dir):
        """Take whatever has been safely processed in temp_dir and move it to the desired location"""

    def fetch_productlinks_saved_in_a_temp_directory(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        retries = 1
        max_retries = 10
        while retries <= max_retries:
            retries += 1
            try:
                # creates a temporary directory to write stuff to
                with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
                    elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
                    counter = 0
                    for elem in elems:
                        elem_url = elem.get_attribute("href")
                        if re.match(".*/code/.*", elem_url):
                            if counter <= 1:
                                self.save_images_plus_meta_into_a_temp_dir(elem_url, temp_dir)
                                counter += 1
                    # If are here, you did not get a stale element reference
                    # You can now transfer data to the desired place
                    self.move_images_plus_meta_into_desired_location(temp_dir)
                    return  # Exit out of the retry loop
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                print(f'Retry count: {retries}')
                continue
        raise Exception('Failed to fetch product links')
```